# Posterior of Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, bayesian, generalized-linear-model

how do we prove that logistic regression has a Bernoulli-distributed posterior?

Also, are there any other link functions within the generalized linear model framework that provide a Bernoulli posterior distribution?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but what is the prior?

Comment: The posterior in this case is the dependent variable conditioned on a specific realization of the vector of independent variables.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you do a significant amount of background reading.  All binary random variables (with all observations having the same two possible values) that are independent have a Bernoulli distribution.  The link function is just the mathematical connection between $X$ and Prob$(Y=1 | X)$ and can be any function you want that is in $[0,1]$ regardless of the distribution of $Y$.